# What do the colors mean on this 1892 plat map?

Tags: legend, features

A while back I happened upon a page from a Plat Map of my hometown from 1892.  I like staring at it and looking for families that were still in town when I was a kid 100 years later, street names that have changed, things like that.

[image: 1892 Plat Map, Marengo, Illinois]

One thing that fascinates me though is the tinting which looks like it may have been done by hand.

The colors appear to group together different annexations made to the town over time, but I've been unable to find a legend to go with the map that might provide additional explanation or insight.  So I'm curious whether there may be any additional significance to the colors (and whether the colors may have had some standardized meaning in plat maps like this).

For reference, digitized copies of the Plat Book can be found [in the McHenry Public Library District collection](https://vitacollections.ca/mchenrypubliclibrary/3456114/page/4?n=) and [at Historic Map Works](http://www.historicmapworks.com/Atlas.php?cat=Directories&c=US&a=8818).

Can anyone provide any insight?

Comment: Makes sure that all lots/ownership adhere to zoning guidelines and restrictions; more details https://nickiandkaren.com/ask-a-realtor/read-plat-map-the-basics/

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how "authoritative" they are, but Art Source International is in the business of selling vintage maps and posters.  According to [Coloring of Antique Maps - Art Source International](https://artsourceinternational.com/map-collecting/antique-maps-coloring/):

> Maps were originally colored to enhance appearance and readability.
> Generally three or four colors (green, pink, orange and yellow)
> distinguished political subdivisions, black was used for names, red
> colored cathedrals or other buildings distinguish large cities and
> blue stands for water.

Although green, pink, orange, and yellow would commonly be used to distinguish political subdivisions, there often was no specific meaning for any one of the given colors.  The fact that none of the colors butt up to themselves leads one to  the [Four color theorem - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem) for coloring political subdivisions to make them more distinguishable.